# Asp.Net Core 2 with Google Auth & Cookie auth on subdomains

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I have 3 web applications on Azure.

- Webapp1 is *www.mydomain.com*
- Webapp2 is *admin.mydomain.com*
- Webapp3 is *user.mydomain.com*

When I log on WebApp1, I want to be logged on all other subdomains.

I want to use social providers to authenticate my users, and use asp.net Identity for authorization.

After reading docs & SO questions here is what I have in my Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /*
     * Some code
     */

    // Creating a blob storage account to share keys for all applications
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityStr"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("identity");
    AsyncContext.Run(() => container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync());

    services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("MYAPP")
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, "keys.xml");

    /* 
     * BEGIN DISGUSTING: I recreate the data protection provider here
     * because I need the instance of it below for the Cookie options
     */
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("MYAPP")
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, "keys.xml");
    var service2 = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var dataProtector = service2.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
    /*
     * END DISGUSTING
     */

    services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    services.AddIdentity<AuthUser, AuthRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                o.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
                o.Cookie.Domain = "mydomain.com";
                o.DataProtectionProvider = dataProtector;
                o.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2"));
            })
            .AddGoogle(o =>
            {
                o.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                o.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            });

    /*
     * Some code
     */
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    /*
     * Some code
     */

    app.UseAuthentication();

    /*
     * Some code
     */
}
```

The cookie is working fine on the Webapp1 but the domain attached is not as the one defined in o.Cookie.Domain but www.mydomain.om

Here is a view of chrome's cookies
[image: cookies]

And fiddler's view:
[image]
I probably missed something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity cookie doesn't have a domain set. You don't need to add Cookie a second time, because Identity already adds it, and you need to configure that instance, not the new one you're creating

So try using [ConfigureApplicationCookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

```
services.AddIdentity<AuthUser, AuthRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(o =>
        {
            // Google options.
        });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
});
```